# Quickly ~ Web Application fails to opendatabase

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, html5

I'm building a Quickly ~ HTML5 Application, it works great until I try to use WebSQL Storage, which fails to open a databse:

`var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 5 * 1024 * 1024);`

giving the next error: **Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18**

The Python code that calls the webview is this:

```
    self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
    self.scroller.add(self.webview)
    self.webview.props.settings.enable_default_context_menu = False
    self.webviewsettings = self.webview.get_settings()
    self.webviewsettings.set_property("javascript-can-open-windows-automatically", True)
    self.webviewsettings.set_property("enable-universal-access-from-file-uris", True)
    self.webviewsettings.set_property("enable-developer-extras", True)
    self.webviewsettings.set_property("enable-html5-database", True)
    self.webviewsettings.set_property("enable-html5-local-storage", True)
    self.webviewsettings.set_property("enable-offline-web-application-cache", True)
    self.webviewsettings.set_property('enable-file-access-from-file-uris', 1)
    self.webview.load_uri(get_media_file('app/index.html'))
    inspector = Inspector(self.webview.get_inspector())

    self.webview.show()
```

What I'm I doing wrong? any help will be apreciated (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to python, but javascript under webkit. Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18-when-i-try-to-set-a-cookie) on Stack Overflow.

To summarise it, you can't use openDatabase over local web pages, you will need to use a full local server.

You can use [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) to start a server from python and connect to it using webview.